# How do the outer planets: Uranus, Neptune and Pluto fit into Judaism?

Tags: science, astronomy, acharonim

It is not a secret that we discover new things in all fields of science, not mentioned in our sources all the time.

We know that in Judaism the 7 planets represent/aligned with 7 spiritual forces and influences, like is [Sefer Hayetzirah 4:12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_Yetzirah.4.12?vhe=Sefer_Yetzirah,_Warsaw_1884&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "ואלו הן שבעה כוכבים בעולם חמה נוגה כוכב לבנה שבתאי צדק מאדים. ואלו הן ז' ימים בשנה שבעה ימי בראשית. ושבעה שערים בנפש שתי עינים שתי אזנים ושני נקבי האף והפה. ובהן נחקקו שבעה רקיעים ושבע ארצות ושבע שעות. לפיכך חבב שביעי לכל חפץ תחת השמים: "
>
> " So now, behold the Stars of our World, the Planets which are Seven; the Sun, Venus, Mercury, Moon, Saturn, Jupiter and Mars. The Seven are also the Seven Days of Creation; and the Seven Gateways of the Soul of Man—the two eyes, the two ears, the mouth and the two nostrils. So with the Seven are formed the seven heavens, the seven earths, and the seven periods of time; and so has He preferred the number Seven above all things under His Heaven."

How did Rabbis fit (if anything) the newly discovered planets into the spiritual system of G-d's Creation?

Comment: Just FYI Pluto is no longer considered a planet

Comment: And the other dwarf planets and the hundreds of asteroids and kuiper belt objects and planets orbiting other stars?

Comment: @JoelK Neither are the sun and moon

Comment: @ba I was merely commenting on the question’s title

Comment: There's also billions of planets elsewhere in the universe

Comment: The point of these are that they are individually visible with the naked eye. The stars are too far away to determine and are therefore grouped into the constellations.

Comment: @DavidKenner In this case he obviously means the rabbis who lived after the other planets were discovered.

Comment: Uranus has always been visible to the naked eye, albeit dimmer.

Comment: @Joel K, but Achronim at the time when Pluto was a planet might have commented on this and included Pluto in their explanation

Comment: @Heshy It seems that there's no clear difference between the 7 planets and the 3 others besides being observed.

Comment: Well, since the Sun and the Moon are not planets, they were probably relieved when  Uranus and Neptune were discovered. They now had 7 real planets. Pluto is a good question - or was, until it lost its planet-status. So we now have 7 planets, as Chazal fortold. QED.

Comment: @DannySchoemann (if you're not kidding) You missed the point. The former 7 all had important qualities, like the Sun (Sunday) and the Moon (Monday). It didn't become Uranday and Neptuday.

Comment: ????? - I've never read it, but I am sure the Sefer Hayetzirah doesn't refer to Yom Rishon as Sunday, nor to Yom Sheni as Monday. And how do Thursday and Friday fit into your naming convention? This intrigues me.

Comment: @DannySchoemann THe point is that all 7 are interrelated as Sh"Y suggests. THe Gemmorah in Shabbos says whoever is born on Tuesday falls under the influence of Mars for example. So it's impossible to throw the Moon away and replace it with Neptune.

Comment: Moses held to a Ptolemaic or geocentric worldview, so he instituted the seven-branched Menorah, representing the seven classical planets orbiting the Earth. Later, the Maccabees, under [Greek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristarchus_of_Samos) influence, changed to a heliocentric perspective, and instituted the nine-branched Menorah, representing the nine modern planets orbiting the Sun. But then Pluto was degraded to a [minor planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_planet).

Comment: @Lucian Wow, never heard of. Neither of Moses geocentric view, nor 7 br Menorah referring to planets nor Mac's 9 br menorah. Where did you take it all from?

Comment: @AlBerko: The seven lights of the Menorah are (obviously) the earthly representation of the seven heavenly lights, i.e., the seven classical planets. As for the latter part, it was (obviously) a joke.